# storing a numpy array in csv greatly increases the file size

Tags: python, csv, numpy, data-analysis

I have two files in csv format. I am doing data analysis on them. I loaded the `file1.csv` in a numpy array named `array1` using `numpy.genfromtxt()` and the other file in numpy array `'array2'`.

```
Size of file1: 80 
Size of file2: 10 MB
```

I then merged the whole data into a single numpy array. After removing some of the columns from the data I output that numpy array into a csv file using `numpy.savetxt()` but the output file size was `700 MB`.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you boil down the code you have to a demonstrative snippet? [ask]

Comment: What is the dtype of your array?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `fmt` argument to `numpy.savetxt()` to specify the formatting used for the numbers. The default format `"%.18e"` results in a 24-character-long scientific notation format padded with trailing zeros. If you know your dtype is int32, you can use a different format that does no padding, such as a plain `"%d"`.